# transformers-cli error: the following arguments are required: --model_type

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am trying to convert a tf checkpoint to a pytorch checkpoint using `transformers-cli` as following

`transformers-cli convert model_type bert --tf_checkpoint bio_bert_large_1000k.ckpt --config bert_config_bio_58k_large.json --pytorch_dump_output pytorch_model.bin`

and am getting the following error

```
usage: transformers-cli <command> [<args>] convert [-h] --model_type
                                               MODEL_TYPE --tf_checkpoint
                                               TF_CHECKPOINT
                                               --pytorch_dump_output
                                               PYTORCH_DUMP_OUTPUT
                                               [--config CONFIG]
                                               [--finetuning_task_name FINETUNING_TASK_NAME]
transformers-cli <command> [<args>] convert: error: the following arguments are required: --model_type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error.. it needs to be `--model_type`, not `model_type`.